# why do I have many UUIDs dsym inside an app archive?

Tags: ios, xcode, uuid, dsym

I've opened the dSYM folder inside an app archive package, and I could see many dSYM files with different UUIDs.

Then I've inspected myApp.app.dSYM file from terminal and I could see which one is the current app UUID.

```
dwarfdump -u .../myApp.app.dSYM 
UUID: 139E5EA8-3443-3C2D-AF69-C6FEE6CCE094 (arm64)
...
```

Are the other files dSYM of previous versions? Or used on different devices>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different UUIDs for different compiler versions. this one is for arm64

some thing like "F9D20636-****** F93643A6639F (armv7)" is for arm7.

same dsym with multiple UUID associates to same binary.

Comment: So why do I have different compiler versions? Is it saving compiled versions from previous machines?

Comment: It depends how many architectures you support. you can check that from ValidArchitecture in BuildSettings.

Comment: I see thanks. And why do I have multiple UUID associated to the same binary? (last line of your answer)

Comment: Multiple UUIDs means that a particular UUID for a particular architecture like UUID as 139E5EA8-3443-*** is for arm64 and F9D20636-** for armv7. but both UUID are of same dsym file.